# C# UWP task that will block execution of code

Tags: c#, uwp, task, messagebox

in UWP how to make task that will block execution of code in current thread? Something like Windows forms ShowDialog() method:

```
int a = 1;

Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();

int b = 2;
```

I have created my custom message box control, I need to implement this functionality.

Comment: Form2 should have `OnClosed` event. You can move your code whatever you want to execute after closing to be executed to `OnClosed`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested that you should try to implement an `async/await` version instead of `PushFrame` version.

You can read [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152137/DispatcherFrame-Look-in-Depth) to know more about `PushFrame`. But this will be no longer be supported in UWP.

---

To implement an `async/await` version. You need to return a `Task` or any other class that has a `GetAwaiter` method in your `ShowDialog` method. Then run the task and `WaitOne` using `AutoResetEvent`/`ManualResetEvent`. In your `Closed` event of your `CustomMessageBox`, `Set` the `AutoResetEvent`/`ManualResetEvent` to let the `Task` return. Then your `ShowDialog` will be continued by your `await.`